# Web service Rest + Mysql + Android

Tags: php, android, web-service

Primeiramente olá a todos, é o seguinte para meu trabalho do curso desenvolvemos uma aplicação web de uma imobiliária com PHP mas a segunda parte deste trabalho é desenvolver um aplicativo android em java para isso queria usar o mesmo banco do site para que os usuários possam interagir com as duas plataformas. Agora vem o problema já vari a internet caçando algum tutorial, livros, videos, artigos e nada que ensine a fazer essa comunicação entre Banco de dados Mysql e Android java, tentei desenvolver web service rest com json(sem exito) a maioria do conteúdo que acho estão obsoletos ou da erros.

Alguém me da uma Luz ai por favor, de indique qualquer coisa que funcione e possa estudar?

Comment: Coloque um exemplo do que você tentou e que erro teve. Ai fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Se você procurou e não achou nada interessante na internet, talvez você está procurando errado. Existem vários framework em PHP para fazer isso. Tente procurar um mini-frame Work. Quando tiver pronto a aplicação web, aí a vc vai para a móbile. Abraços

Comment: JSON é "universal", basicamente qualquer linguagem já tem bibliotecas para conseguir ler JSON, inclusive o Java. Dessa forma o aplicativo (Java)  se conecta com o PHP (que se conecta com o MySQL) e retorna em JSON, o JSON é interpretado pelo aplicativo.

Comment: Pode encontrar, nesta mesma página na parte direita, uma lista de perguntas sobre o mesmo tema na coluna com o titulo "Relacionado"